# kable indent rows with specific hspace for all columns

Tags: r, knitr, kable, kableextra

The following code add indentations to the 2nd & 4th rows for first column only.

```
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(head(mtcars[ ,1:4]), "latex") %>% 
  add_indent(positions = c(2, 4))
```

Wondering how to add indentations of specific hspace to the 2nd & 4th rows for all columns. Something like this

```
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(head(mtcars[ ,1:4]), "latex") %>% 
  add_indent(positions = c(2, 4), hspace = "2em", allCols = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a version of the `add_indent` function that adds this option. Doing it this way ensures that kable options such as `digits` are applied consistently in each row.

```
add_indent = function(kable_input, positions, allCols = FALSE) {
  out = kableExtra::add_indent(kable_input, positions)
  if (allCols){  
    table_info <- magic_mirror(kable_input)
    for (i in positions + table_info$position_offset) {
      rowtext <- table_info$contents[i]
      table_info$contents[i] <- gsub(' &', paste(' &', kableExtra:::latex_indent_unit('')), rowtext)
      out <- gsub(rowtext, table_info$contents[i], out, fixed = T)
    }
    out <- structure(out, format = "latex", class = "knitr_kable")
    attr(out, "kable_meta") <- table_info
  }  
  return(out)
}


kable(head(mtcars[ ,1:4]), "latex", align = 'l') %>% 
  add_indent(positions = c(2, 4), allCols = T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`add_indent` is indeed only made for the first column.

A workaround would be to add the indentation manually in your data frame:

```
head(mtcars) %>%
  mutate_all(., funs(ifelse(row_number() %in% c(2, 4), 
                            paste0("\\hspace{1em}", .), .))) %>%
  kable(format = "latex", booktabs = T, escape = F)
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @broti for very useful answer. This first convert the numeric columns to characters which do not respect the proper alignment. Please see row 2 and 4 of column `drat` .

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - are you saying that numbers should be right-aligned instead of left-aligned?

Comment: This is a good workaround. However, it transforms all numeric columns to characters outside `kable`.  So `kable` arguments `digits` and `align` will not work properly. Need a solution something like this `knitr::kable(head(mtcars[ ,1:4]), "latex") %>% 
  add_indent(positions = c(2, 4), hspace = "2em", allCols = TRUE)`.